# I am trying to use an if and concatenate nested statement

Tags: calculated-column

The formula reads:

```
=IF(([Potentially Impacted]="N/A")
    ,CONCATENATE("Potential Business Impact is to:"
                 ,[Potentially Impacted Units]"
                 ,"  "
                )
   )
```

and I keep getting the following error message.
The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. 
Learn more about the syntax for formulas.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a quotation mark before `[Potentially Impacted Units]`

Answer (score 2):

I reformatted your formula, easier to read and the mentioned quote is more obvious. linebreaks and space will be ignored when you save the Formula.

It can be shortened to:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Potentially Impacted])
    ,"Potential Business Impact is to:"&[Potentially Impacted Units]&"  "
    ,""
   )
```

[This Bookmarklet](https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster) helps with checking formulas while you type